# How to add search engine to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine

I have two questions:
1. What does "Path Contains (optional)" mean? (the last box in four)
2. There are a search engine name Coccoc. Address: http://coccoc.com/search
How can I track it's traffic in Google Analytics as Organic.

This is how I do it: http://www.caominhblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/add-search-engine-coc-coc.png
But it still tracks as referral. I'm not sure the Query Parameter is right or not.

Thanks for your help.